# When Would I Need Windows "Remote Desktop Session Host"

Tags: windows, windows-server

It is possible to connect to a remote Windows server using a Remote Desktop client without any additional configuration. So, in which cases would I need to enable the `Remote Desktop Session Host` using the Server Manager? What is the difference between it being enabled and disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Windows Server comes with the possibility of doing two administrative
remote desktop connections.

To have more than two client sessions open at the same time,
each user and device that connects to a Remote Desktop Session host
needs a client access license (CAL), which you can buy from Microsoft
and install on Windows Server.

References :

- [License your RDS deployment with client access licenses (CALs)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license)
- [Remote Desktop Services roles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-roles)